# returning a fixed size 2D array to web3.js

Tags: solidity, arrays, web3js

I would like to return a 2D array from solidity code and look at it with web3.js

this is the solidity function:

```
uint8 [10][10][100][100] public blocks;
function getBlock(uint x, uint y) returns (uint8[10][10]) {
    if (x < blockStoreSide && y < blockStoreSide) {
        return blocks[x][y];
    }
}
```

but what I get back from `getBlock` in web3.js is this number:

```
0xf5027db1aeac4c95acf2c3c32651cfd3f5561906399e19bd14818a6c7cc2d9cb
```

My assumption is this is an address?

I tried `web3.eth.getStorageAt` for that address but I just get zeros, not what I actually set the value to.

the ABI looks okay to me:

```
{ constant: false,
  inputs: 
   [ { name: 'x', type: 'uint256' },
     { name: 'y', type: 'uint256' } ],
  name: 'getBlock',
  outputs: [ { name: '', type: 'uint8[10][10]' } ],
  type: 'function' }
```

So how do I actually read the storage?   More general question, how can I efficiently read large amounts of storage?

Answer (score 3):

The hex number you got back was a transaction hash. If you want to read from storage, you should add the `constant` keyword to your function:

```
uint8 [10][10][100][100] public blocks;     
function getBlock(uint x, uint y) constant returns (uint8[10][10]) {
    if (x < blockStoreSide && y < blockStoreSide) {
        return blocks[x][y]; 
    } 
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `call` method.

```
myContract.getBlock.call(3,4)
```

Comment: how embarrassing.  thanks.  Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: it was a 2 part question:  If I want to read a large array it seems most efficient to read getStorageAt, but how do I find the address of the 4d array?

Comment: if I return the 4d array I quietly run out of gas (i.e. nothing programmatically, just something in the miner logfile)